# Azure API Management Test Console Stopped Working

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have been creating some APIs in API Management and since yesterday the Test Console seems to have broken and it's not available anymore. It does provide the following message:

The Azure portal test console isn't supported in API Management services deployed in an internal virtual network.

I haven't enabled it virtual networks and I have verified that the Vnet option is disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue and the azure team fixed it, if you still see the issue then clear the cache and reload the page.